# publishing two topics from stm32 microcontroller but only one topic is showing on pc

Tags: c++, stm32, ros, bluepill

Im using stm32 bluepill board with rosserial to publish two topics which are "right_wheel_ticks" and "left_wheel ticks".

Here is the code of main.cpp file.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include "../Inc/rosserial/ros.h"
#include "../Inc/rosserial/std_msgs/Int16.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
ros::NodeHandle nh;

std_msgs::Int16 right_wheel_tick_count;
std_msgs::Int16 left_wheel_tick_count;

ros::Publisher rightPub("right_wheel_ticks", &right_wheel_tick_count);
ros::Publisher leftPub("left_wheel_ticks", &left_wheel_tick_count);

long delay = 500;
long cur_time_right = 0;
long pre_time_right = 0;
long cur_time_left = 0;
long pre_time_left = 0;

const int encoder_minimum = -32768;
const int encoder_maximum = 32767;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(rightPub);
  nh.advertise(leftPub);


  //nh.negotiateTopics();

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    HAL_Delay(100);
    nh.spinOnce();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USB;
  PeriphClkInit.UsbClockSelection = RCC_USBCLKSOURCE_PLL_DIV1_5;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA1 PA3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA2 PA4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI1_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI3_IRQn);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void RightWheelPulseCount(){
    cur_time_right = HAL_GetTick();

    if ((cur_time_right-pre_time_right)>delay){
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2)){
            if (right_wheel_tick_count.data == encoder_maximum) {
              right_wheel_tick_count.data = encoder_minimum;
            }
            else {
              right_wheel_tick_count.data++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (right_wheel_tick_count.data == encoder_minimum) {
              right_wheel_tick_count.data = encoder_maximum;
            }
            else {
              right_wheel_tick_count.data--;
            }
        }

        rightPub.publish(&right_wheel_tick_count);
        pre_time_right = cur_time_right;
    }

}

void LeftWheelPulseCount(){
    cur_time_left = HAL_GetTick();

    if ((cur_time_left-pre_time_left)>delay){
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)){
            if (left_wheel_tick_count.data == encoder_maximum) {
              left_wheel_tick_count.data = encoder_minimum;
            }
            else {
              left_wheel_tick_count.data++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (left_wheel_tick_count.data == encoder_minimum) {
              left_wheel_tick_count.data = encoder_maximum;
            }
            else {
              left_wheel_tick_count.data--;
            }
        }
        leftPub.publish(&left_wheel_tick_count);
        pre_time_left = cur_time_left;
    }
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){
    if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_1){
        RightWheelPulseCount();
    }
    else if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_3){
        LeftWheelPulseCount();
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

The code does not give any build errors.

after debugging the code to bluepill board I connected the board to my ubuntu pc.

I run this command in terminal to connect the bluepill via rosserial,

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_nodes.py /dev/ttyACM0
```

When I run `rostopic list` in terminal it only shows `/left_wheel_ticks` topic

```
/diagnostics
/left_wheel_ticks
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

what can I do to setup both "left_wheel_ticks" and "right_wheel_ticks" topics to publish?

here is my code repository
https://gitlab.com/dinoj.supunsara/tick_count

Comment: The code does not look C, why have you used the tag [tag:c]?

Comment: the code is a c code written in stm32cubeide , I have changed thecode extention to .cpp because to work with rosserial we need the file to be in .cpp format

Comment: Yeah, that means you're writing C++, not C. These are two completely separate languages. The syntax you are using throughout is C++. It has no chance of successful compilation with a C compiler. I removed the C language tag from your question.